# I need help about bill checking code with Python in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So guys my goal is to get multiple inputs which is float values from user and check that values in the excel folder with in a range of columns and rows given by user such as A1 to A20 and if that value exists, I want to color that cell green, if it does not exist I want to color it red.

So the thing is I manage to handle that but I can't take multiple values from user to check in Excel folder even if I took multiple inputs that time program is checking the last input and saving as a result of last input not the others. Also I need to check if there are same values and if they exist I need to control over bill number

Here is my code

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

from openpyxl import workbook

wrong_fill_pattern = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='FF0000')

right_fill_pattern = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='008000')

starting = (input("Bill Starting Spot `Sample A1` : "))

ending = (input("Bill Ending Spot 'Sample A20' : "))

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

s = wb["Sheet1"]

billtocheck = float(input("Enter a bill : "))

for j in s[f'{starting}':f'{ending}']:
    for cel in j:

        print(cel.coordinate, cel.value)
        if cel.value == billtocheck:
            rightcoordinate = cel.coordinate
            s[f'{rightcoordinate}'].fill = right_fill_pattern
            print('+')
        else:
            wrongcoordinate = cel.coordinate
            s[f'{wrongcoordinate}'].fill = wrong_fill_pattern
            print("-")

    print('-------------')
wb.save("TEST2.xlsx")
```

its just a something like prototype i cant brainstorm anymore because i am newbie and i cant find proper openpyxl informations about my program ( i know there is a site of openpyxl i checked it )
any ideas ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to your existing code where you take the User's input;

You can change the Users input for the 'bill' to accept multiple values and then include this in the 'for' loop.
Some methods to accept multiple inputs can be implemented by;

1. having the User enter multiple comma (or delimiter of your choice)
   separated values and convert that to a list of float values.
2. having the User enter values which are added to a list until they
   enter 'return' only

The additional code below has both options, you can comment out each to test the other.

With Option 1 the user enters all their bill values at the prompt separated by a comma like;

```
Enter a bill : 5.5555,516.78,24.68,666.66,54.32,1.1111,10.999
```

When they hit 'return' the input is assigned as the string variable, 'btc'. This string variable is then converted into a float list, 'btc_list' using  List Comprehension.

With Option 2 a continuous While loop prompts the User to enter their bill value at the prompt. The code then checks if a value was entered and appends that value to the list, btc_list as a float value. Since the While loop remains True it is runs again to prompt the User to enter a value.
If the user enters 'return' without a value the code 'breaks' out of the While loop.

In the for loop where previously all cells in the range (e.g. A1:A20) were checked against the single input value. An extra level is added to read each float value from the btc_list before running this check.

```
for billtocheck in btc_list:
```

If a match is found and the background changed to green the check for that cell is terminated using the 'break' so the cell is not changed back to red.

```
...
### Input Option 1 comma separated list 
btc = input("Enter a bill : ")
btc_list = [float(item) for item in btc.split(',')]

### Input Option 2 User enters values at prompt until 'return' only is entered 
# btc_list = []
# while True:
#     enter_bill = input("Enter a bill or return to exit : ")
#     if enter_bill == "":
#         break
#     else:
#         btc_list.append(float(enter_bill))

for j in s[f'{starting}':f'{ending}']:
    for cel in j:

        for billtocheck in btc_list:
            print(cel.coordinate, cel.value)
            if cel.value == billtocheck:
                rightcoordinate = cel.coordinate
                s[f'{rightcoordinate}'].fill = right_fill_pattern
                print('+')
                break
            else:
                wrongcoordinate = cel.coordinate
                s[f'{wrongcoordinate}'].fill = wrong_fill_pattern
                print("-")

    print('-------------')
wb.save("TEST2.xlsx")
```

If the cell range and bill inputs are large the looping thru the range for each bill may take a while.

---

Alternate method to achieve same result with less processing

This method for achieving your same result uses a dictionary; range_dict, to store all the cells in the entered range, e.g. A1:A20. The dictionary will contain one entry for each cell where the 'key' is the Cell coordinate and the value is the Cell value. The same loop also sets all cells to red background initially.

In the second loop we iterate thru the list of bills entered by the User. It checks if the bill value is found anywhere in the dictionary range_dict. If it is we then use a loop called List Comprehension to obtain the Keys for all occurrences of that bill value and place into the list; found_list. The keys added to found_list are the cell coordinates so we can then loop thru the list and change those cells to green (from the red background we previously set them all to).
The loop then cycles to check the next bill value.

So you can see, if a bill value is not in the cell range there is no looping thru all the cells, the if/then test

```
if btc in range_dict.values():
```

is False and the cell remains with the red background.

If a bill value is in the cell range, we obtain all cells that match then loop thru and change each to the green background.

```
...
btc = input("Enter a bill : ")
btc_list = [float(item) for item in btc.split(',')]

# Create the range_dict with all cells coordinate as key and cell value as value
range_dict = {}
for j in s[f'{starting}':f'{ending}']:
    for cel in j:
        range_dict[cel.coordinate] = cel.value
        s[f'{cel.coordinate}'].fill = wrong_fill_pattern

# Iterate thru the entered bills to check if exists in the range. If so change to green.  
for btc in btc_list:
    working_list = []
    if btc in range_dict.values():
        found_list = [key for key, value in range_dict.items() if value == btc]
        for celcoordinate in found_list:
            s[f'{celcoordinate}'].fill = right_fill_pattern

print('-------------')
wb.save("TEST2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much man the option 1 worked pretty fine there is only one thing left to do  and that is checking if the value exists multiple times on row program has to put me in a confirmation section like it is going to ask me the bill number for example 3923428123 and confirm if it is matches and seperate the same vaules. Thanks A Lot AGAIN!!!!

Comment: @Mehmet the code as is will find all matches for each bill entered by the users since you are checking all cells in the range against each bill value whether the range is a row, column or combination. Not sure if that is what you needed to confirm in your comment above. For your interest I have added an alternate method to do the same operation that does not cycle thru the whole range for each bill entered so may be faster and  uses slightly less code.